# SignalR Core and receiving messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

Does it make a difference how to send messages to all clients of the hub?

For example JS:

```
hubConnection.invoke("Send", message);
```

Or maybe send request via Fetch with the text of message to the "/chat" adress and then checks were carried out in the body of the controller. So after a message will add to the database and sent to clients like this:

JS with request to controller adress:

```
async function postData() {
    let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
     const response = await fetch('/Home/Index', {
                 method: 'POST', 
                 headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 },
                              
    body: "message=" + message 
});
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string message)
{
   // Here your logic
   // ************
   //------------------
   await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveMessage", message);
   return new EmptyResult();           
}
```

Is it worth the second way to send messages or is it easier to send them via JS as in the first option and additionally address another request to the database?

Comment: Usually you'd do it from the Hub. So from the `Send` Method of the Hub you'd update the db and do `Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveMessage", message);`. Then it'd be the first option

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth the second way to send messages or is it easier to send them via JS as in the first option and additionally address another request to the database?

If you just want to exchange [simple&small message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.1#buffer-management) (that can be added to DB within your hub method) between client and hub server, the first approach is better, which would not require additional HTTP request to controller action.

Comment: Suppose that some client app on specific environment does not support websocket, but it still want to send message/notification to another connected SignalR clients, your second approach would help achieve it.

Comment: Hi @Overmastered, if the reply is helpful, you can accept it as answer.